# Xamarin Media Manager LockScreen Player Display Image

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, plugin.mediamanager.forms

I am using Xamarin MediaManager plugin to play videos. When playing a video and assigning a valid image to the MediaItem, the image is not shown on iOS notification player. Ideally what i want is below
[Expected behavior image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqB7l.png)

What i have tried is

```
        var mediaItem = await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(cisiTVPopUpViewModel.VideoURLUri);

        mediaItem.DisplayImageUri = "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/726/200/300.jpg?hmac=9WbqvM6W7D0BwVEyvVbC2xL9ulSQpXyoTcL3O89modM";
        //mediaItem.AlbumImageUri = "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/726/200/300.jpg?hmac=9WbqvM6W7D0BwVEyvVbC2xL9ulSQpXyoTcL3O89modM";
        //mediaItem.ImageUri = "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/726/200/300.jpg?hmac=9WbqvM6W7D0BwVEyvVbC2xL9ulSQpXyoTcL3O89modM";
```

after checking for some time i got this workaround

```
            CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(item);
            var cover = UIImage.FromFile("cisitv_clock_solid.png");
            CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Title = "Test Title";
            CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.DisplayImage = cover;
            //CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.AlbumImage = cover;
            //CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Image = cover;
            CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.IsMetadataExtracted = false;
          CrossMediaManager.Current.Extractor.UpdateMediaItem(CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current);
```

Which produces below results

What i am doing wrong here ? Any help is much appreciated.